# Angular repeat not updating after ajax call ONLY on my school network

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, angularjs

I am displaying a table via angularjs, php, mysql, and insert into that table via php/ajax refreshing after the call via

`angular.element('#myId').scope().loadData();`

When I use my insert form on my home computer, laptop, mobile phone, friends house, parents house, local cafe it will insert the data into the database fine and update the angular table via the above command, but when running this on my schools computer it will only insert into the database and not refresh the table? I have been stuck on this for several days, and my professor doesn't quite know what would be causing this. We tried adding:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

But it made no difference.. could it be some special network configurations at the school? I know there is not much information, but maybe someone has had a similar problem and can help here any suggestions are appreciated.

In simple my ajax post works on any network/pc besides my schools.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same angularjs version? Maybe it is the mysql version or something is failing when in different environments. Probably even php version.

Comment: @MichelTomé It is all hosted on my server with bluehost so the versions would be the same, angularjs version doesn't change as its in my header file displayed on all pages.

Comment: Does it behave like that on all browsers?

Comment: @NewDev Correct, ie, chrome, firefox all do not update the table on school PC, but when running chrome, firefox on my laptop right beside me(at school which is the weird part as im connected to their network via wifi) it works and updates the displayed table.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have script loading order issue. And doing something like `angular.element('#myId').scope().loadData();` to initialize is definitely not the Angular-way

Comment: @NewDev it is the only way I could figure out as i'm new to angular, there is 0 erros in the console and i am getting the exact same console output on the laptop, as well school pc object, object, object just the table on school pc doesn't update while others will

Comment: Show relevant parts of `.loadData` implementation. And look into `module.run` to initiate loading the data and services - to deliver it.

Comment: try `angular.element(document.querySelector('#myId')).scope().loadData();`